# Group a date field by month in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, group-by

I have a date field (`Model.expires_on`) and I need to group the records by month and get the sum of the `Model.amount` field. I can do:

```
Model.all.group(:expires_on).sum(:amount)
```

But when I try to group by month I cannot get it. I have tried:

```
Model.all.group(:expires_on.month).sum(:amount)
```

Comment: I have SLQLite in dev/test and Postgresql in production. Your solutions give me an error on SQLite. I have though about migrating to Postgresql for dev/test enviroments, is it a good advice?

Comment: Yes, that is good advice. You should be using the same database in dev, test, and production. Database portability is largely a myth unless you do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

For Postgresql this should work

```
 Model.group("date_part('month',expires_on)").select("date_part('month',expires_on) as expiration_month ,sum(amount) as sum_amount")
```

You may also be able to use depending on your SQL Provider as Postgresql does not have a month function

```
Model.group("MONTH(expires_on)").select("MONTH(expires_on) as expiration_month,sum(amount) as sum_amount")
```

The objects in this collection will then respond to `expiration_month` and `sum_amount`

Know that this will combine all months regardless of year